# R Bubble chart: labels overlapping

Tags: r, direct-labels

Attempting to code a function that returns a bubble chart from aggregated data.

I'm passing it a column of a data.frame in "agg".

```
aggs2 <- function(agg, deporur=0, all=TRUE){

  ##create aggregate from library data

  agg1 <- aggregate(agg, by=list(NoNA$IMD_NATIONAL_QUINTILE, NoNA$UR), 
                    FUN=function(x) c(mn=mean(x), n=length(x)))

  ##bind into a dataframe

  agg1 <- cbind(agg1[,1:2], agg1[,3])

  ##add column holding values of Deprivation Quantile and Urban/Rural status

  agg1$NewCol <- do.call(paste, c("Deprivation Quantile", agg1[c("Group.1", "Group.2")], 
                                  sep = " "))

  ##set column names

  colnames(agg1) <- c("Deprivation", "Urban and Rural", "Mean", "Count", "DepUR")

  ##remove categories with low counts

  if(all==FALSE){

    agg1 <- subset(agg1, agg1$Count > 9)

  }

  ##order data.frame by mean

  agg1 <- agg1[order(agg1$Mean, decreasing=TRUE),]

  ##create bubble chart
  if(deporur==1){

    radius3 <- sqrt(agg1$Count/pi)

    symbols(factor(agg1$DepUR), agg1$Mean, circles=radius3, inches=0.35, 
            xlim=c(0,10.0), ylim=c(min(agg1$Mean-0.25),10.0), fg="white", bg="purple",
            xlab="Deprivation Quantile and Urban/Rural Status", ylab="Mean Response")

    text(factor(agg1$DepUR), agg1$Mean-.1, agg1$DepUR, cex=0.7)
  }

  #return ordered dataframe
  agg1

}
```

This returns a sorted data.frame by mean, and the following chart:

[image: Deprivation and Urban/Rural]

Because this function will need to create graphs from a variety of different documents and columns, I would like to code it so that the labels do not overlap the bubbles, or other labels.

I have looked at the directlabels library, but I have been unable to work out how to code it properly.

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: One thing that might help (but wouldn't solve your problem entirely) would be to shorten your labels.  Since they all start with "Deprivation Quantile" you could drop that.  And you could abbreviate Rural and Urban.  That would leave you with 2R, 3R, 2U, 1U, 3U, etc.

Comment: Funnily enough, in the end this is what I've done.  DQ4R, DQ3U, etc.  For now, this will work, at least until I get into longer questions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any solution for non-overlapping labels with regards to other labels AND other circles. Nevertheless, `wordcloud::textplot` might be a starting point:

```
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10), size = sample(10:20, 10), lab = paste0("label", 1:10))
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
with(df, {
  plot(x, y, cex = size, pch = 19, col = adjustcolor("violet", alpha.f = .4), main = "non-overlapping")
  textplot(x, y, lab, new = FALSE, show.lines = FALSE, cex = 2)
  plot(x, y, cex = size, pch = 19, col = adjustcolor("violet", alpha.f = .4), main = "overlapping")
  text(x, y, lab, cex = 2)
})
```

[image]